# Algorithm for finding the most common repeating pattern in a potentially irregular string/array

Tags: python, algorithm, count

Apologies if this question is a repeat of available questions. Haven't found one that's quite what I am looking for.

I am interested in detecting patterns in strings/arrays such as `ABCABCABCABC` where this could equally well be encoded by integers. My application is such that I am working with streaming sensors where each letter in the aforementioned sequence would be one sensor (e.g. `A` is a sensor). Because of sensor failure and whatnot, my sequences are not always quite periodic/repeating. They can come out like this e.g. `BCABCABCAB` or `ABCBCBCA` because of various failures.

My application is made harder because a priori I do not know how many sensors there are in my dataset so I require an algorithm to infer that number from the sequence (like those given above). Alas, the algorithm should yield `ABC` for all the given examples, as this is the longest and most common pattern.

One idea I had was simply to something like:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

# ABCABCABCABC encoded with integers 
A = np.array(
  [[ 1 ,2, 3],
   [ 1 ,2, 3],
   [ 1 ,2, 3],
   [ 1 ,2, 3]])

c = Counter(map(tuple, A)).most_common()[0]

# ((1,2,3), 4)
```

But this seems rather inefficient as I would have to reshape the array multiple times (and a potentially lot of times, since my sequences are very long and, recall, I do not know a priori that the length of my repeating sequence is 3), and then run `Counter` each time to assess the regularity of an appearing (or not) pattern.

Other ideas including using the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm along with n-grams or some combination thereof. Alternatively calculating the suffix tree.

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

More details:

- Size of data: sequences of length between 1000 and 1000000 ish (though the upper bound is quite unlikely)
- Sub-sequences *cannot* have repeated entries, they have to be unique. I.e. a sub-sequence cannot be `ABB`. The reason is quite simple; ultimately I am interested in the temporal evolution of each individual sensor.

Comment: How do you know which order the sensors will record their data in?  Is there some guarantee that the longest sequence will be some multiple concatenation of the expected string `ABC`, or could it be a multiple concatenation of some permutation such as `BAC`, or `CBA`, etc?

Comment: I do not know the order either; but my assumption is that they are repeating. So the order could well be `CBA` or `BAC` but if that is the case, then I expect that to be repeating. And added complication is that at `t=0` one of the sensors could be missed so it only logs `CB` but not a `A`. This is true for the whole experment, sensors dropping out here and there.

Comment: To infer the number of sensors, couldn't you just take the size of the `set()` of your input? And then possibly start calculating permutations of the set, and the number of occurrences of each permutation?

Comment: I'd start by recognising (and counting) n-grams. Maybe later evolving to dictionary search. Or maybe some Markov chain.

Comment: https://hal-upec-upem.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00620792/document (and the  string-search book by Crochemore for even more inspiration) Your "letters" won't repeat constraint will probably make things simpler, your "infinite alphabet" rule will complicate it a bit.

Comment: I mean the upper limit on the number of characters in my alphabet is what is available in the sequence itself. If I run set() from python on the above strings I'll get A, B, C. So my alphabet is not infinite, but can only use the available sensors IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I came up with this, please try to break it.

```
from nltk import ngrams
from iteration_utilities import all_monotone

def find_longest_monotonic_increasing_ngram(seq):
    # Store stats
    gram_stats = {}
    # Find longest common subsequence / n-gram
    M = []
    for m in range(1,int(0.2*len(seq))):
        gram = Counter(ngrams(seq, m)).most_common()[0]
        # Check if gram is monotonically increasing (i.e. is it sorted)
        if all_monotone(gram[0],strict=True,decreasing=False):
            gram_stats[m] = gram
            M.append(m)

    return max([gram_stats[m][0] for m in M], key=len)
```

MWE:

```
A = np.tile([1,2,3], 30)
# Mess up
A = np.insert(A,0,[1,2]) # One missing sensor at t = start
A = np.append(A,1) # two missing sensors at t = final
A[50] = 2 # Missed sensor reading at t=50 
# Run
find_longest_monotonic_increasing_ngram(A)
>>> (1, 2, 3)
```